# PSTN Connection

Tags: cisco, telephony, voice

So I have a CUCM sever setup and a few phones setup, I have a 1841 router as the default gateway for the network and I am looking at branching out from just internal extension calls.

I have a VWIC-1MFT-G703 card In the 1841 router and wondered if this router can be setup as a voice gateway to allow me to make calls to the PSTN.

If so can someone tell me how I can achieve this and a provider for doing this that's not super expensive. I am only in a lab so I don't want to spend loads.

Comment: The 1841 has no voice capabilities. (and NE frowns on cross-posting: https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/voice-over-ip/pstn-voice-gateway-1841/m-p/3203057)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"just in a lab" and "few extensions" makes me think your PSTN calls will be few; in which case you're better off with a SIP supplier, local to your country.

Comment: I shall have a look

Comment: ... Some suppliers will give you an incoming-only number for free, and some will give you free calls between their own numbers; also can get test trunks for limited periods.  All very helpful for establishing whether it works adequately, especially configuration, echo etc.  Likely to be much better than provisioning a G.703 line.  Also consider a VIC2-4FXO if you have POTS lines available.